# Overload = operator in c#

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Lets say I have the class:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
    public int Value { get; private set; }        
}
```

I will like to do the following:

```
var f = new Foo(1);
f = 5; // How can I do this? In here I want to change => f.Value
var x = f.Value; // I will like x to equal to 5 in here
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **C#** you can't override the assign operator (`=`).

What you can do is defines implicit conversions:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator Foo(int value)
    {
        return new Foo(value);
    }
}
```

This allows you implicitly convert from `int` to `Foo`:

```
Foo f = 5;
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx) is a list of overloadable Operators in **C#**.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your question, if you really need to change the value of Value, why don't you make the setter of Value public, so that you can just use,
f.Value = 5

Comment: OP wants to override assignment operator....and this is not answer but comment

Comment: Its just that my constructor takes way more parameters and I was just curios. +1 thanks for the help